# Set front-end product in stock / out of stock of each product

Tags: magento2, stock-status

I tried to modify the product's `frontend stock status`. First I got my stock for each product that is different for `each customer` in my `outside database`.

How can I make the customization in magento such that, **if customer is logged in**, the loaded product status will change based on the **customer id** and **product sku**, **but it will not change the backend product status**.

For example, customer with `id = 1`, and `product sku = A0001`, at my `outside database, the specific product quantity is 1000`, so the product with `sku A0001` will display the status to `in stock`, but when customer with `id = 2` and `sku = A0001` is logged in, at my `outside database, the quantity is 0`, so the product with `sku A0001` will display the status to `out of stock` for **customer 2.**